# Rewriting old/deprecated code java

Tags: java, jsf, uml, reverse-engineering

The company I work at has a piece of code they would like to rewrite. It uses Java/Java server faces. The problems with it are that it is old and uses depreciated code, was written in an IDE that is no longer available and doesn't work well with netbeans, and that it is kind of sloppy coding in the first place. No one really knows its structure and there is limited documentation.

Before beginning on the rewrite, we would like to find the structure of the old program and get a decent UML diagram. What tools would work the best in this situation? So far we have looked at one called Agilej.

Sorry if this is a little vague, I'm just a lowly intern an haven't been filled in on everything yet =p

Answer (score 2):

You can use [JArchitect](http://www.jarchitect.com), a pretty complete java static analysis tool

Answer (score 1):

I'm not giving clickable hyperlinks as you should be able to find them easily through a web search and there may be more than 1 link that is useful for you

**Sparx Systems Enterprise Architect** has very powerful reverse engineering capabilities. Java (also compiled binary JAR) is in the list of supported languages.

I have used Enterprise Architect's reverse engineering features several years ago to help us understand and design modifications of legacy C++, QT code.

Enterprise Architect was able to automatically retrieve the class model. I then used the raw class model to drag/drop draw several other diagrams including only classes of my interest with level of detail I needed etc.

In the range of other **static code analysis** tools (e.g. the code flow visualization) I don't know which tool particularly supports Java well enough. Quick Google points e.g. to **Coder Gears JArchitect**. In the past project I have mentioned we used **Doxygen**'s automatically generated documentation. Part of that were also some automatically generated **graphviz** dependency diagrams.

To clarify the design and visualize the flow (especially big legacy functions) I have found useful the **Rapid Quality Systems Code Rocket** flow visualizer

Once you get the basic facts at your hands through the various reverse engineering tools next step would be to go through them, annotate what is the unknown, what is doing what, basically apply some **formal code review** method (e.g. **Fagan inspection** or some of its derivatives).

(using evaluation versions of the various tools may be enough if you think ahead what are the required deliverables for your follow up actions. I guess the company is not planing to give you a >0$ budget)

The **Agile Modeling** site may have some good **refactoring** tips and some minimal UML mapping guidelines, start e.g. at [Agile Legacy System Analysis and Integration Modeling](http://www.agilemodeling.com/essays/agileLegacyIntegrationModeling.htm)